# Is it possible to specify the size of an image/sprite in C++/SDL?

Tags: c++, sdl, 2d-games

I'm creating a game similar to [this](http://www.addictinggames.com/action-games/fishy.jsp) and I'm attemptin to figure out how to generate randomly sized enemy fishes. As far as I can tell, the sprites you create in SDL take on the size of the image you give them, but what I want to do is be able to specify a size for my image when the fish is created dynamically using random values for its size.

My assignment uses SDL and a framework given to us, so I can't import any fancy libraries.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: You may have better answers if you post this question on [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: does your framework support resizing? You have the following choices: 
1. You can create a smaller bitmap by taking every nth pixel to a new surface.
2. Use SDL_rotozoom, which is not included with SDL.

Comment: Just wondering if you needed a more detailed answer from my part?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called `scaling`. You can check this [tutorial](http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-scale-surface) to easily add the feature to your game. The suggested `rotozoom` can be found in `SDL_gfx`, available [here](http://www.ferzkopp.net/joomla/content/view/19/14/).

If you are going this route and decided to write your own code for learning purpose, just keep in mind that manually scaling a `SDL_Surface` is expensive, so you should probably do it only when you're spawning the fish and store the surface for the lifetime of the fish.

Another option would be to make a 2D game using 3D graphics; basically you just stretch the triangles any way you want and the texture will adjust itself to fill it.